# Unity: how to release update without rebuild all game?

Tags: unity

I have a game with a lot of asset (textures, 3d model etc), that reach 1 gigabyte of datas.

If i plan to release new prefabs and models, what's the best approach ? How to not create new builds and force my users to download everytem 1+ gigabytes ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do patches in games work?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/39933/how-do-patches-in-games-work)

Comment: See also [previous questions & answers about Unity asset bundles](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=asset+bundle)

Comment: This question seems subjective, in that, I don't know how you are patching your game. For some distribution platforms, replacing meshes that are embedded in unity games, shouldn't take that much more to download, regardless of how the meshes were added to the project. However, if you're patching by comparing and overwriting whole files, then that's a whole different beast. In short,... how much it takes to patch a game, depends on how your patcher works.